# Create a windows form application with no border

Tags: windows, border

I am new to Visual Studio and trying to create a few simple pages which look like windows 8 no border style.
Like [this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/53823134/how.png)

Can you suggest some good reference to do so. I have been through youtube, but due to lack of exact keywords I was not able to find appropriate results.

I want to create a window that looks like plain paper and have rectangular buttons on it, same as the Visual Studio 2012 Splash window.Which is moveable from anyplace except Buttons.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Windows do you wish to target? Windows 7? Windows 8?

Comment: I am using Windows 7, but can use Windows 8 if i have to.

Answer (score 0):

Its very easy, follow these steps very carefully:

1. If Properties window is not Opened then, Open it from View Menu (Second from Left), Select **Properties** OR Press **Ctrl+W** and then **P**
2. Select Form from MainDesign Windows ( Form1.cs[Design] )
3. Select **FormBorderStyle** from Properties Windows and Select **None**. Your Form has no Borders now!

Please mark it as answer if it solved the problem.

Enjoy..